# How do I set the user agent in simplewallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, rpc

For using simplewallet in RPC mode. Also, are there any limitations in terms of length or characters that are not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the user agent, when you are launching simplewallet you want to do something like the following:

```
./simplewallet --wallet-file <filename> --password <password> --user-agent <user-agent> --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --rpc-bind-port 18082
```

So you use the `--user-agent` flag.

At this time, I do not know the limitations of user agent characters/length.